# SBT: How to exclude source files and documentation from the assembly?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using the plain assembly plugin with SBT but along with the assembled package, I get extra packages like:

```
mypackage_2.11.jar
mypackage_2.11-javadoc.jar
mypackage_2.11.-sourcesjar
```

Is there any way to skip those packages with SBT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should disable the generation of these JARs (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html):

```scala
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. When I run local it still generates the jar. When I run in jenkins it still generates all three :(